# Kubernetes NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod

Tags: kubernetes, calico, cni

regarding to below logs which I used describe pod, my pods stuck in pending state due to “FailedCreatePodSandBox”

there is some key note:
-I use calico as CNI.
-this log repeat multple time, I just past here this one as sample.
-the ip 192.168.90.152 belong to ingress and 129 belong to tiller in the munitoring NS of k8s and I do not know why k8s try to bind it to another pod.

I google this issue and got nothing here I’m.

```
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m56s                   kubelet, worker-dev  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "2abca59b55efb476723ec9c4402ede6e3a6ee9aed67ecd19c3ef5c7719ae51f1" network for pod "service-stg-8d9d68475-2h4b8": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "service-stg-8d9d68475-2h4b8_stg" network: error adding host side routes for interface: cali670b0a20d66, error: route (Ifindex: 10688, Dst: 192.168.90.152/32, Scope: 253) already exists for an interface other than 'cali670b0a20d66'
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m53s                   kubelet, worker-dev  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "ec155fd442c0ea09b282a13c4399ae25b97d5c3786f90f1a045449b52ced4cb7" network for pod "service-stg-8d9d68475-2h4b8": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "service-stg-8d9d68475-2h4b8_stg" network: error adding host side routes for interface: cali670b0a20d66, error: route (Ifindex: 10691, Dst: 192.168.90.129/32, Scope: 253) already exists for an interface other than 'cali670b0a20d66'
```

can any one help on this issue?

Comment: How you installed calico - as a ds?

Comment: @bimal-vasan yes as ds, one on my worker and one on master.

Comment: which version of Calico do you use?

Answer (score 1):

As per design of CNI network plugins and according to Kubernetes network [model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/), Calico defines special IP pool [CIDR](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cidr) `CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR` to determine what IP ranges are valid to use for allocating pod IP addresses across k8s cluster.

When you spin up a new Pod on a particular K8s node Calico plugin will do the following:

- Check whether the Pod exists on this node;
- Allocates IP address for this Pod from within defined [IPAM](https://www.projectcalico.org/calico-ipam-explained-and-enhanced/)
  range;
- Creates an virtual interface on the node's host and appropriate
  routing rules in order to bridge network traffic between Pod and
  container;
- Register Pod IP in K8s API server.

You can fetch the data about Calico virtual interfaces on the relevant node, i.e.:

```
$ ip link | grep cali

 cali80d3ff89956@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
 calie58f9d521fb@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default
```

In order to estimate the current issue , you can consider to query Calico `install-cni` Pod's container logs and retrieve the data about the certain Pod `service-stg-8d9d68475-2h4b8`, searching for the existing virtual interface mapping:

```
kubectl logs $(kubectl get po -l k8s-app=calico-node -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}' -n kube-system) -c calico-node -n kube-system| grep service-stg-8d9d68475-2h4b8_stg
```